# Execute windows shell command and process output variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, terraform

In Python 3.7 running on Windows, what specific syntax is required to:

```
1. Navigate to a directory containing a terraform program  
2. Execute "terraform apply -auto-approve" in that target directory  
3. Extract the resulting output variables into a form usable in python
```

The output variables might take the form:

```
security_group_id_nodes = sg-xxxxxxxxxx  
vpc_id_myvpc = vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Want to be using windows cmd style commands here, NOT powershell.

My first failed newbie attempt is:

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\\path\\to\\terraform\\code')

from subprocess import check_output
check_output("terraform apply -auto-approve", shell=True).decode()
```

Comment: why don't you start but showing what you have tried, this would be fairly easy using subprocess and os

Comment: @d_kennetz I added something simple.  The reason I did not include it at first is because it is so little.  I would like help understanding how to approach this simple building block so that I can build from it.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @downvoters  Post a link to what you think the answer is or a suggestion of how to improve the question.  No drive by shootings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your output, but subprocess could definitely make the trick.

Try something like:

```
command = 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
TARGET_DIR = 'E:\Target\Directory'
subprocess_handle = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), cwd=TARGET_DIR, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess_handle.wait()

result = subprocess_handle.communicate()[0]
print(result)
```

Worked for me once, just play around with params.

UPD: Here I assume that "terraform" is an executable.

Comment: Terraform is an executable.  However, the code you are suggesting just hangs indefinitely without giving any output to interpret what is happening.

Comment: @CodeMed, could be so. Much depends on how the program works. Did you try with `print()` to check if it hangs on `wait()` or somewhere later? Options are: trying 'shell=True', using subprocess asynchronously (i.e. without waiting it to finish), also the program may not be writing anythong to stdout (sample's trying to get it). I'm afraid method of trial and error is most of the job here.

Comment: The following prints out the in-process results `subprocess.run("terraform apply -auto-approve", shell=True, check=True)`.  And the program runs successfully.  But then how do I pipe the output into some sort of processing so that I can extract the output variables?  But so that I can still see the running output in the command line to be able to understand what is happening?

Comment: @CodeMed, instead of using `shell=True` you could just print the output yourself in Python code (or/and use it somehow). Not totally sure about detais but `run()` should also support stdout redirect. Thus, communicating should work. Something like "reading output until program terminated". Cannot also point to an asynchronous recipe, but only because I'd have to Google for it myself =)
Hope, you don't use waiting anymore, do you?